# set content type response in ext.data.store

Tags: xml, extjs, content-type

I am using ext.data.store to implement an auto-complete Combobox in extjs 4.0

```
var RecordDef = Ext.data.Record.create([
    {name: 'description', mapping: 'description'},    
    {name: 'lat'},
    {name: 'lng'}           
]);

var ds = new Ext.data.Store({
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url:'geo-multi.xml'}),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    },
    reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
        totalRecords: 'count',
        record: 'result'
    }, RecordDef)
});
```

The problem is am receiving text/html as a response type header after checking firebug:

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  409
Content-Type    text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date    Sat, 07 Apr 2012 13:59:33 GMT
Last-Modified   Sun, 08 Jan 2012 08:11:37 GMT
Server  Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10
```

can anyone help me setting the correct content type header to text/xml ?

Comment: which web server are you using for serving xml file?

Answer (score 0):

not sure which language are you using on server side but you should make sure that correct content type is set on server response

if you are using PHP then you can use this method to set content type

```
// We'll be outputting XML
header('Content-type: application/xml');
```

**check here:**

[change mime type of output in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152006/change-mime-type-of-output-in-php)

Comment: am not using php to generate my XML file, am using an XML file directly...is there anyway to set the content type header directly from my JS file ?

Comment: then the server should set it properly, based on extension, so which server are you using for fetching this file ? (apache ?) and can you check if the server sets correct MIME type based on extension in response header?

Comment: the extension of my file is .xml, and am not using an apache server...if am using a php file i can set the content-type header using the header header("Content-type: application/xml"); but how can i parse the PHP xml output into my comboobx using ext.data.httpproxy (cross domain requests are invalid in this case)

Comment: then your web server should set default content type for the response based on MIME type (extension) of the file, so can you check if there is any setting in your server for that, apache does that automatically using `/etc/mime.types` file